# Unable to install packages using yum in ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud

I am new to AWS and wanted to create an ec2 instance and tried to install httpd package `(yum install httpd)`. Unfortunately, I was not able to do that and getting the following thing everytime. I tried some of the things like  ***Allowing all outbound trafic***, but no use. Any help on this?

```
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
```

Could not retrieve mirrorlist https://amazonlinux-2-repos-us-east-1.s3.dualstack.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/2/core/latest/x86_64/mirror.list error was
12: Timeout on https://amazonlinux-2-repos-us-east-1.s3.dualstack.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/2/core/latest/x86_64/mirror.list: (28, 'Resolving timed out after 5000 milliseconds')

One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown),
and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

```
 1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

 2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
    upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
    distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
    packages for the previous distribution release still work).

 3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
        yum --disablerepo=<repoid> ...

 4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
    will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
    again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

        yum-config-manager --disable <repoid>
    or
        subscription-manager repos --disable=<repoid>

 5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
    Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
    so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
    slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
    compromise:

        yum-config-manager --save --setopt=<repoid>.skip_if_unavailable=true
```

Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: amzn2-core/2/x86_64

Comment: You can share the security group attached to this instance. And make sure the instance has outbound internet access via HTTP/HTTPS.

Comment: have you tried this https://serverfault.com/questions/545164/aws-linux-ec2-yum-wont-run-with-plugins?

Comment: @ArpitJain  I have added both inbound and outbound rules to allow http/https traffic. No use. It seems the issue is I can't access the internet from the ec2 instance, because when I use `ping` there is 100% loss of data

Comment: 2 possibilities, 1 Created ec2 instance in public subnet and no public ip attached to it, 2 created ec2 instance in private subnet with no NAT gateway or no route to internet in route table.

Comment: Yes, Agree with @VikramS , make sure you have enabled "Automatically assign a public IP address to your instances" while creating the instance.

Comment: @VikramS I have selected auto assign a public IP while creating the ec2 instance, and a public IP is assigned. More over when I click on subnetID, I can see there is an attached internet-gateway